# Where do I need to use Offer ID when I use Google Play in -app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm learning  Google Play  in-app in Android Studio with the official sample [project](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/PlayBillingCodelab) .

I have also read the article [Sell subscriptions in app with the Play Billing Library 5](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/play-billing-codelab#2).

I don't know why I need set Offer ID  for an Offer item, I have read the sample code, It seems that project use only the OfferTag in the project.

Where  do I need to use Offer ID when I use Google Play  in -app  in Android Studio?

You can see the Image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the codelabs project you've shared, they only use Offer Tags to show how things work. But in a real situation, you'll probably need both Offer IDs and Offer Tags.

> *Use `Offer IDs` to identify and keep track of purchases in your app's*
> *code. This is important for giving the right subscription benefits to*
> *users based on their chosen offer.*

> *Use `Offer Tags` to sort and analyze your offers in the Play Console*
> *and maybe in your app. This helps you figure out how well different*
> *offers are doing and make smart choices about your subscription plan.*

Just remember, Offer Tags are like extra info you can add if you want, but Offer IDs are a must for every in-app offer you make on Google Play.Here's where you typically use Offer IDs:

**Granting Subscription Benefits:**

- You use Offer IDs to identify the specific offer or subscription that a user has chosen to purchase.
- This identification is crucial for providing users with the correct subscription benefits within your app.

**In App's Purchase Handling Code:**

- When processing in-app purchases within your app, you integrate Offer IDs into your code to distinguish between different subscription options.

Here's a simple example in Kotlin:

```
// Assume you have an Offer ID for a subscription
val offerId = "your_offer_id"

// When processing a purchase, use the Offer ID to determine the type of subscription
fun processPurchase(offerId: String) {
    // Check the Offer ID and grant corresponding benefits
    when (offerId) {
        "premium_monthly" -> grantPremiumMonthlyBenefits()
        "premium_yearly" -> grantPremiumYearlyBenefits()
        // Handle other cases as needed
    }
}

fun grantPremiumMonthlyBenefits() {
    // Code to grant benefits for monthly subscription
}

fun grantPremiumYearlyBenefits() {
    // Code to grant benefits for yearly subscription
}
```

*Remember, Offer IDs play a crucial role in ensuring that users receive the appropriate benefits based on their chosen subscription, and you integrate them into your app's purchase handling logic.*

So, to sum it up, Offer IDs are for tracking purchases, and Offer Tags are for organizing and analyzing your offers. You'll likely need both for in-app subscriptions in most cases.

Hope it helps!